# Find function names in a module

Tags: rust

How can I get a vector of the names of functions stored in a module, similar to how this works in Python:

```py
import inspect
inspect.getmembers(module)
```

I'm trying to write a basic REPL as a learning exercise and want to add line completion, The output type doesn't matter so much as long as it's usable.

1. Is this possible in Rust?
2. Is there a library already designed for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rust is a static language and does not have any kind of introspection at runtime.
[racer](https://github.com/phildawes/racer) is the *de facto* standard tool for Rust completion. I don't know whether it could be used for a REPL (should be, it can complete as one types) or even if it can be used as a library though (its `Cargo.toml` suggests it).